# Why do these CSS pseudo selectors break Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

After a bit of working backwards, I discovered the following lines of CSS were preventing Chrome Dev Tools from live editing CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .projects-* .v-center.row {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }
  .projects-* .v-center.row > * {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
}
```

Any CSS written after these lines appeared in the Chrome Dev Tools inspector as:

```
 styles.css:1
```

and was unable to be debugged.

Is there anything particularity incorrect about this CSS or is this simply a bug in Chrome?

Comment: It's very unlikely that it's a bug in Chrome. Maybe it was the line directly after these?

Comment: After removing these lines, everything seems to work just fine and the CSS after this point is pretty straight forward in terms of syntax.

Comment: Is .projects-* a valid CSS selector?

Answer (score 0):

They're not "breaking" Chrome devtools; it's ignoring them because it has no idea what to do with such invalid selectors. Instead of `.projects-*`, you need to do something like

```
*[class*='projects']
```

Any CSS linter would have pointed that out.

I assume that devtools is then deciding that the whole file is bollixed and therefore it does not want to let you live-edit the remaining rules.